# How to fix "Could not locate bower" error while migrating from Vaadin 13 to Vaadin 14

Tags: npm, vaadin, bower

I am trying to migrate my Vaadin application from 13th version to 14th. I am following the migration guide: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/v14-migration/v14-migration-guide.html step by step.

Everything is going well till I have to upgrade *Polymer2* to *Polymer3* following this guide: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/v14-migration/migration-tool.html

Executing the following command `mvn vaadin:migrate-to-p3`
 returns the `com.vaadin.flow.migration.MigrationToolsException: Could not locate bower. Install it manually on your system and re-run migration goal.` but I have the bower installed globally and locally.

`bower -v` returns `1.8.8`

This is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "no-name",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@polymer/polymer": "3.2.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10",
    "polymer-modulizer": "^0.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.8.8",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "raw-loader": "3.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-babel-multi-target-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1"
  },
  "description": "This project can be used as a starting point to create your own Vaadin Flow application with Spring Boot.\r It contains all the necessary configuration and some placeholder files to get you started.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://git.ws.com.pl:3000/ck/vaadin-mi.git"
  },
  "author": ""
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you happen to have an example you could attach to this bug ticket? https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6587 Seems to be a bug in migration tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem running the migration tool on Windows 10.

As a workaround, I used Docker to run it :

- install [Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop)
- run a [Maven image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven), I use Maven 3 and openjdk 11 (mount your maven repo to prevent re-downloading all dependencies) :

  `docker run -it --rm -v c:/[path to your maven repo]:/root/.m2/repository -v c:/[path to your maven project]:/usr/src/myproject -w /usr/src/myproject --entrypoint "/bin/sh" maven:3-jdk-11`
- then, in the container, install node and npm :

  `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -`

  `apt-get install -y nodejs`
- install bower :

  `npm install -g bower`
- allow running bower with root

  `echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc`
- run the migration tool

  `mvn vaadin:migrate-to-p3`